# How do I solve ORA-01843: not a valid month eror

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am having an issue trying to insert data into a view I created, but it keeps telling me that the month I inserted was not valid.

```
INSERT INTO V_DRIVER
(DRIVER_LICENCE, SSN, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, HIRE_DATE, STATE) 
VALUES( 'AR18263', '9576852', 'Jack', 'Mosby', '09/22/1975', '01/05/2000', 'CA') ;
```

Error message:Error report -
ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: By applying [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) with appropriate [date format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) not relying on the default

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the columns are dates.  So, use `date` constants.  In Oracle, these use the `DATE` keyword and the `YYYY-MM-DD` format:

```
INSERT INTO V_DRIVER (DRIVER_LICENCE, SSN, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, HIRE_DATE, STATE) 
    VALUES( 'AR18263', '9576852', 'Jack', 'Mosby',
            DATE '1975-09-22', DATE '2000-01-05', 'CA') ;
```